# How can i remove a root node from a json after converting from xml, using java

Tags: java, json, xml

I have the following code with me:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Xml2Json {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
           
    }
}
```

It gives the output as shown below:

```
{
  "users": {
    "report": {
      "sub": "eng",
      "score": 30
    },
    "user": {
      "name": "test1",
      "age": 20
    }
  }
}
```

But i want to remove this root node, and the expected output is:

```
{
  "report": {
    "sub": "eng",
    "score": 30
  },
  "user": {
    "name": "test1",
    "age": 20
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.get(map, path). You may extract data and convert it to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing just assign the root node value to `jsonObject`

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(jsonObject.keys().next());
System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

You can also specify the name of the root node directly

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("users");
```

**Output:**

```
{"report":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}}
```

Comment: Thank you! can u suggest what can i do if i want to rename this name, that is 'users' to 'employees'

Comment: `jsonObject.put("employees", jsonObject.remove("users"));`